# Substitution method in complexity theory

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, fibonacci, substitution, asymptotic-complexity

Please advise if this answer should be moved to maths forum.

I'm quite confused about how we simply complexity theory equations.

For example, suppose we have this small Fibonacci algorithm:

---

[image]

---

And we're given the following information:

[image]
[image]

---

What I struggle to understand is how the formula `T(n)` is expanded and simplified, especially this:
[image]

what am I really missing here?

Thanks

## Edit

This was taken from this [book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/sample/0262533057chap27.pdf) in page 775.

Comment: The first step is clear since F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}. The second step is indeed a bit unclear since b-Theta(1) may be negative.

Comment: Exactly, although I found the last 3 step very hard to understand @Henry

Comment: I think the author might have made a meal of this derivation. For example, I see no particular reason for the constant term `b` to be positive; I don't even see why it is the *only* other term, since F<sub>n</sup> grows very fast (it is exponential, so there may theoretically be infinitely many polynomial and "polyrithmic" terms in-between). Besides, in the definition of ϴ notation the only required factor is `a`.

Comment: @Henry The literally next phrase in the book is `if we choose b large enough to dominate the constant in the Theta(1)`

Comment: I honour each one of you for understanding the phase, It would be highly appreciated if you could walk me through each phase and clarify. @user58697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rephrase the claim:

> There exist some `a` and `b` such that T(n) < aF<sub>n</sub> - b

Now start the proof with

> Chose `b` large enough to dominate the constant term.

Now the last inequality should be clear.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but my confusion lies in the simplification in the last 3 steps. So for example, how can a(F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2}) - 2b + ϴ(1) be simplified to aF_n - b - (b - ϴ(1))?

Comment: @S.Nas just basic algebra and the definition of Fibonacci numbers, nothing mysterious.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, really appreciate it.I'll revisit some algebra to help me understand this. Thanks :)